# How to change tty login prompt?

Tags: terminal, login, prompt, tty

To be clear, I am not referring to `/etc/issue` (shown before the prompt) or `/etc/motd` (shown after login), but the prompt itself, which is currently

```
hostname login:
```

For good measure, I am running Arch Linux, but I believe the answer will likely be cross-distro.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My background is RHEL-derived distributions (mainly Fedora, today), Arch is foreign to me.

Back when `/etc/inittab` and `mgetty` where used by RHEL, you could edit  `/etc/inittab` and pass the `-p` option to `mgetty`. This would set the prompt.

Now with the adoption of `systemd` `/etc/inittab` is empty. The tty configuration file is now `/lib/systemd/system/getty\@.service`. This file seems to use `agetty` instead of `mgetty` to manage the tty. `agetty` man page doesn't show the `-p` option, but you could reinstall `mgetty` and use it. Or you could use the `-n` (no prompt) option with the `-l` (specify a login program) option and write a wrapper to `/bin/login` with your own prompt.

Now, I don't know how to set this up on Arch, but you have to find out where it manages its ttys (`/etc/inittab` is the first place you have to look), then see with the tty program how to roll your own custom prompt.

Comment: Aha! Thank you, this is getting me on the right track. I've discovered that Arch uses `agetty`, and found the invocation inside /etc/inittab. Unfortunately, agetty does not seem to have an option to change the prompt. (Oh I just reread your answer, you said that for me haha). It seems like your ideas are the best possible options. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Create a systemd service file in /etc/systemd/system/ to run a one line bash script with "chvt N" in it.

For details, see my post: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=231082

Worked well for me. I'm thinking there has to be a setting for this that could be edited or whatever, but after several hours, I gave up looking for it. The versatility and configuration options of systemd seem awesome. Now if I could just figure out how to find/use them properly.

EDIT TO ADD INFO (Oct 28th 2017):

Also for details on how to do this, see: [systemd - Change default login tty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399986/systemd-change-default-login-tty/401103#401103)

Please correct errors or explain simpler solutions via posting, rather that just down voting or pointing out errors.